# Module numpy not found error after installing Python 3.8.6

Tags: python, numpy, module, python-3.8

I took a little break with programming, and it turns out my python version 3.8.2 was not up to date. I went to the python website and downloaded the latest version 3.8.6. I use VScode, and it recognized that I was up to date and I made it my active version. The moment I switched the versions, I received this error when I ran the code in terminal:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/holca/Desktop/Connect4/cannect4.py", line 1, in <module> import numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy`

I am also getting this error message in the warnings section:

```
Unable to import 'numpy'
```

Once I switch back to python 3.8.2, it still works great. Now I have 2 questions:

1. Should I stay with python 3.8.2, and forget that this ever happened since there isn't much of a difference in the updates, or should I try to get to the bottom of this and try to get the module numpy to work again on the latest python version?
2. If you think it is worth it, or you know the solution to my problem, what do you think is the reason for this problem, and what can I do to get numpy to work?

I checked to see if anything else was out of the ordinary, but everything seems to work. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: When running python 3.8.6, what is the value of `sys.path`?

Comment: how do I check that

Comment: Run this code under python 3.8.6: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: You installed NumPy on Python 3.8.2. You didn't install it on Python 3.8.6. Python packages need to be installed on the Python version you're using.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I thought packages were installed only by major version number?  i.e. python 3.8.<anything>

Comment: It says 
['c:\\Users\\holca\\Desktop\\Connect4', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\holca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: And where is `numpy` installed?

Comment: I did the command 'pip install numpy' and it says that the file is already there

Comment: I am not sure I do not see

Comment: Run `pip --version` and show us the output

Comment: pip 20.2.3 from c:\users\holca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

Comment: If you can easily switch back to python 3.8.2, you can see where numpy is installed by doing `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)`

Comment: That looks like the problem -- numpy is installed for 32-bit python, not 64-bit.  Do you recall if you installed the 32-bit version of python originally?

Comment: yes I installed the 32

Comment: Then that's the problem.  You need to install numpy again, this time with the 64-bit version of pip (wherever you installed that).

Comment: So I need to uninstall the 32 bit and install on the 64? how do I do that?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Windows, but as I recall, the control panel has an icon for removing installed software.  Try that.

Comment: I basically just told it to uninstall then install am I right?

Comment: Uninstall the 32-bit and then install the 64-bit.  And make sure the 64-bit location is on your PATH.

Comment: I went to the cmd and said to uninstall then install, I will see how it goes

Comment: it doesnt do anything, I do not know how to direct it to my path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222329/discussion-between-nfs-07-and-john-gordon).

Comment: I resolved it, basically what I did is COMPLETELY erase everything associated with python, and I downloaded the 3.8.6 installer and interpreter, then in cmd, since the 3.8.6 was in the PATH I simply asked the pip to install NumPy externally. Thank you all for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the installation create a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv test
cd test
source bin/activate
```

verify that you are running the correct version of python with

```
python -V
```

Then install nump

```
python -m pip install numpy
```